# Why isn't the jumping animation showing?

Tags: java, swing, animation, game-physics

I'm a beginner programmer and I recently started trying to make a game in Java.

It's very basic and doesn't include any classes (although it should) but anyway I tried to make a jumping animation on the `JPanel` using a `JLabel` as my sprite but whenever I try to time the space between each movement of the label by using `Thread.sleep(millis)` the Java seems to skip it and moves the label to the last position.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("malario");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(700, 700);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

panel.setLayout(null);
panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
JLabel malario = new JLabel("Malario");
malario.setOpaque(true);
malario.setBackground(Color.green);
panel.add(malario);

malario.setBounds(100, 550, 50, 50);

JLabel platform = new JLabel();
platform.setOpaque(true);
platform.setBounds(0,600,700,50);
panel.add(platform);
frame.setContentPane(panel);
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    int originalx = 100;
    int originaly = 550;
    int currentlocx = originalx;
    int currentlocy = originaly;

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            malario.setBounds(currentlocx+10,currentlocy , 50, 50);
            currentlocx = currentlocx+10;
        }

        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            malario.setBounds(currentlocx-10,currentlocy , 50, 50);
            currentlocx = currentlocx-10;
        }
        int jumpy=0;
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            jumpy= currentlocy-100;
            while(jumpy!=currentlocy){

                malario.setBounds(currentlocx,currentlocy-10 , 50, 50);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                currentlocy = currentlocy-10;
            }
        }
    }
});

}
public static int Time(){
    return (int)System.currentTimeMillis();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Thread.sleep().

All listener code is executed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), which is the Thread responsible for handling events and painting the GUI. So, when you tell the Thread the sleep the GUI can't repaint itself until all the code in the loop has finished executing, so you only see the component at its last position.

Instead you need to use a `Swing Timer` to schedule the animation. Read the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are sections on:

1. `Concurrency in Swing`- explains more about the EDT
2. `How to Use Swing Timers` - for examples on using a Timer

for more information.

Also, don't use a KeyListener. Instead it is better to use `Key Bindings`. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Key Bindings`.

Edit:

See: the `KeyboardAnimation` example from [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for a working example that shows both:

1. how to use key bindings
2. how to do animation.